# UIPickerView is Selecting the Wrong Row-Swift

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, uipickerview

So I have UIPickerView that isn't working the way I want it to. It works correctly about 3/4 of the time, but the other 1/4 it doesn't.

```
 func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    return listsArray.count

}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, viewForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int, reusingView view: UIView!) -> UIView
{
    activeQuizPlace = row
    var pickerLabel = UILabel()
    pickerLabel.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    pickerLabel.text = listsArray[row]
    pickerLabel.font = UIFont(name: "Georgia", size: 22)
    pickerLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
    return pickerLabel
}
```

The listsArray contains 5 items(which are strings). Rows 0-2 work correctly 100% of the time. However when row 3 is selected it occasionally says that row 1 was, and when row 4 is selected it sometimes says that row 2 was. I think the problem has something to do with the last function I have that controls the UIPickerView. I just copied that code from this website as a way to change the color and font of the text. Before I was using this function I never had a problem with it, or at least never noticed one. Side note: I am using Xcode 6.3.2

I need a way for the picker view to work correctly, as well as to be able to change its font and color. I would love help with this I've been looking for answers online for 2 hours and can't figure out what I'm doing wrong, thanks in advance!

Comment: can you also post your didSelectRow method?

Comment: This is all of the code that I'm using related to the picker view. This is my first time using UIPicker view, so I'm not positive what exactly I'm doing, maybe not having that is the problem? I was just  getting the rows value within that last method with activeQuizPlace = row

Comment: hi, so if I am not wrong, you are using the activeQuizPlace value for getting which row the user selected, right? This is not the correct way to do this. To correctly handle the selection, you need to implement the UIPickerViewDelegate protocol and implement the didSelectRow method.  Check out this tutorial: http://sourcefreeze.com/ios-uipickerview-example-using-swift/

Comment: That would be correct. I went through that tutorial and used the didSelectRow method there and it fixed the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need to remove the line `activeQuizPlace = row` from the code you have shown and then add this function below.

```
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    activeQuizPlace = row
}
```

The function you were using is not called with the index that the user selects, it is called with the index that the system needs for drawing the views.

The suggested function should be the one you are after (hopefully).